# New DVD drive shows in BIOS but burn software does not see it

Tags: windows-7, bios, dvd

I installed a new hard drive with a fresh install of Windows 7. I added a DVD drive. It shows up in BIOS, Device Manager (no yellow marks) AND in "Computer". I have tried several different burn software and NONE can find the drive when I go to burn. One program DID act like it was burning it (took 40 minutes!) but no data when I put the DVD in another computer. At one point I inserted a DVD with a file on it and it showed up in Windows Explorer.

Comment: are you positive your drive does in fact have burn capabilities?

Comment: Please provide specifics